# Setting the size of a ReportViewer report manually

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

What I need to do is to add subreports to a report that can grow or shrink dynamically, depending on how much data is available to display.  Is there any way to set these to do that?  Google tells me there's a CanGrow/CanShrink functionality, but it only seems to effect textboxes.

Comment: there is nothing that prevents subreports to span multiple pages. I can look up how I did it for some of our reports, but I don't remember setting anything special. what are the contents of your subreports? tablixes?

Comment: I have some static layout reports, s few of them are in tables.  They may look like letters to a customer, with their name, address, etc... being dynamically filled in by a dataset.  There are 72 pieces of this document.  Some are empty, and shouldn't even show up.  Others have some tabular data.  I need to figure out how to make it use the least amount of room on the report, so there aren't large gaps.  I figured if I put them all on a main report and sized them small, I could make it so they all could be seen in design view with minimal scrolling, but would expand to the proper size when run

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you ask for this, but you can add your subreports inside the parent table of your main report. Follow this link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2011/01/02/walkthrough-add-a-subreport-in-local-report-in-reportviewer/

Is for asp.net but I have followed this guide to make the same for windows Forms.